# show popup once daily

Tags: cookies, popup

I want to show popup box once a day using cookie
what i'm using to show tinybox popup is

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   window.onload = function()
   {
      TINY.box.show({html:'Hello',autohide:20,width:400,height:320});
document.getElementsByClassName('tmask')[0].onclick=null;
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     function getCookie(c_name) {
         var c_value = document.cookie;
         var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
         if (c_start == -1) {
             c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
         }
         if (c_start == -1) {
             c_value = null;
         } else {
             c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
             var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
             if (c_end == -1) {
                 c_end = c_value.length;
             }
             c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start, c_end));
         }
         return c_value;
     }

     function setCookie(c_name, value) {
         var c_value = escape(value);
         document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
     }



     function checkCookie() {
         var showed = getCookie("showed");
         if (showed != null && showed != "") {
             var date = new Date(showed).getDate();
             var currentDate = new Date().getDate()

             if (currentDate > date) {
                 return true;
             }
             return false;

         }
         return true;
     }

     if (checkCookie()) {
         TINY.box.show({
             html: 'Hello',
             autohide: 20,
             width: 400,
             height: 320
         });
         document.getElementsByClassName('tmask')[0].onclick = null;
         setCookie("showed", new Date());
     }
 });
```

Comment: my bad luck not working, http://tinybox222.googlecode.com/svn/tinybox.js this file also included in code hope this may help to get solved

Comment: please take a look at this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/kenfly51/Xtvdt/) . it work perfectly. have you used firebug or devtool to trace on the console?

Comment: I don't know why but this code is not working in my windows 7, i installed php, mysql in my laptop while without jquery it work, Thank you MrF it wirks on blogger and Jsfiddle I tested

Answer (score 1):

Use this code. I have tested & it is perfect.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/raw/master/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">                                         
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if( $.cookie('showOnlyOne') ){
                //it is still within the day
                //hide the div
                $('#shownOnlyOnceADay').hide();
            } else {
                //either cookie already expired, or user never visit the site
                //create the cookie
                $.cookie('showOnlyOne', 'showOnlyOne', { expires: 1 });

                //and display the div
                $('#shownOnlyOnceADay').show();
            }
        });
        </script>     
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="shownOnlyOnceADay">
            This text should only be shown once a day!
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Tested it by changing system date.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a cookie like this

```
if(getCookie("showed")!="1"){
  TINY.box.show({html:'Hello',autohide:20,width:400,height:320});
  document.getElementsByClassName('tmask')[0].onclick=null;
  setCookie('showed','1','1')"
}
function getCookie(c_name)
{
   var c_value = document.cookie;
   var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
   if (c_start == -1)
   {
       c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
   }
   if (c_start == -1)
   {
       c_value = null;
   }
   else
   {
       c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
       var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
       if (c_end == -1)
       {
         c_end = c_value.length;
       }
       c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
    }
    return c_value;
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
   var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

Comment: not working, i'm using jquery cookie plugin , "if(getCookie("showed")!="1"){ " work with $(document).ready(function()  but not with what im using